# How to bring git master branch up to date with a named branch?

Tags: git

Me and my homework parter are new to git and managed to mess with the branches somehow. I'm not sure how we got to this state or what to do from here.

There used to be a branch named "lior's_saturday_work" which my partner tried to merge back into the project and this is the result.

[image]

How do we bring the `master` branch up to date with the `lior\'s_saturday_work`?

Comment: **Please read [Pro Git: 3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging)**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this please :

```
git checkout master
git merge lior's_saturday_work
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing the other way around at first:
`git checkout lior's_saturday_work` and then `git checkout master`. Why didn't that work? is it because it's "against" the flow?

Comment: I'm not sure but you should move to master then update it with merge command, just like we did below.

Comment: @Shookie `checkout` does not merge branches, `merge` does. You checkout the branch that you want to merge into (`master`), then you merge in the other branch.